# How to slice data with groupby() function?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, slice, feature-extraction

I am doing a ML project. After preprocessing data I need to do feature extraction. In my dataset, I have 25 classes (alphabets in the datasets) and there are 20 subjects (how many times I got the alphabet) for each class. With the function `groupby()` they (25*20 = 500) all have the same size (1000). I want to compress 1000 sampling points to 50 sampling points by calculate `maccs` column mean.

My dataset looks like this:

[image: My dataset looks like this]

This is what I tried but it did not work. It gives a 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iloc' error.

```
for i in np.arange(211, 890, 20):
  new_dataset = new_dataset.groupby(['alphabet', 'subject'])['maccs'].iloc[i-10:i+20,6].mean(axis=0)
```

How can I access row and columns while using `groupby()` function? Or what can I use to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

alpha_df = pd.read_csv(##path to .csv file)

alpha_gb = alpha_df.groupby(['alphabet','subject'])
alpha_agg = alpha_gb.agg({
     'mccs' : 'mean'
})
agg_alpha_df = alpha_agg.reset_index()
```

Here, I Assume you want to first categorize by `alphabet` and then categorize by `subject` column. because the order of column names in the `groupby()` matters.
By the way, this can be done in single line

```
grouped_df = alpha_df.groupby(['alphabet','subject'])['mccs'].reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But, the first is more explicit and adjustable.
you can look [here](https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/) for more aggregate operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to do something different. Like you said I combined alphabet and subject columns. Then I resample each of them to have 1000 sampling points. Now I am trying to *maccs* column to resize 1000 sampling points to 50 but firstly I need to calculate *maccs* columns’s 50 rows mean not all 1000 rows. I'm having trouble how to slice data with *groupby()*.

Comment: Sorry, still I didn't get what you try to do.If you want to `groupby` just the first 50 lines; then `alpha_df.loc[:50, :].groupby(['alphabet','subject'])` can use

Comment: Thank you it worked but not completely what I wanted. I want to take average every 50 out of 1000 sampling points how can I do it? `for i in np.arange(211, 890, 20):
  new_ds = new_dataset.iloc[i-10:i+20].groupby(['alphabet', 'subject'])['maccs'].mean()`. I tried this but it just gives one line.